# Sort out alphabetically

Tags: python-3.x

```
file = open("resultsA.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        x = line.split(",")
        a = x[0]
        score_one = x[1]
        score_two = x[2]
        score_three = x[3]
        names = sort(a)
        maximum = max(score_one + score_two + score_three)
        print(names + "-" + maximum)
```

I've made this code which I have successfully tested and outputs the maximum values of a set of variables. However, I've been trying to organize the variable "names" so that it outputs all the names alphabetically however it has not been working and I'm presented with this error:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAohT.png)

Comment: post the error as text (run your code in a console)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. The error I receieve as a text is as followed

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nightly\Desktop\Python\Task 3.py", line 42, in <module>
    names = sort(a)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `x[0]` (later `a`) is the first entry on a line, `sort(a)` will not work as expected. Even the implementation of `sort` is missing here (`sort` is not a built in, may be you meant `sorted`?)

You have to build a list with names and scores and sort the whole list.

Try something like this:

```
file_results = open("resultsA.txt", "r")
lines_splited=[line.strip().split(",") for line in file_results]
lines_sorted=sorted(lines_splited, key=lambda v:v[0])
results=[(name, max(a,b,c)) for name, a, b, c in lines_sorted]

for name, score in results:
    print(name+"-"+score)
```

My resultsA.txt for testing:

```
C,2,1,0
A,1,2,3
B,3,4,1
```

Result when running the script:

```
A-3
B-4
C-2
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this helped me understand my code significantly more and I was able to tweak my code and get it to work. Thank you so much!